# Universal Image Loader not working after upgrade to new version 1.9.5

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using the library Universal Image Loader. I moved to Android Studio and it is still working fine. But if I use a higher version than 1.9.1 I get errors in my code.

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
```

"cannot resolve symbol" is the error that Android studio is showing me.
Did they remove this from the library? I cannot find a hint in the changelog.

The problem is that "ImageLoadingListener" is not resolved any more and I cannot find a solution around it.

```
private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;
            public ImageView image;
            public TextView count;
            public TextView counter;
        }
```

I added following to the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: I know it's a silly question but did you add it to `gradle` ?

Comment: I add what I added to gradle. The other imports are working

Comment: Note that [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) has been discontinued by its author, as of November 2015. I would recommend that you drop back to 1.9.1 for the time being, and then develop a plan for eventually moving to another image-loading library.

Comment: oh I did not know this. I tried to update because something in my code causes the TrustManager security warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They had changed the package for listner. You need to change your import to

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
```